# set value on select2 multiple from php with laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

here in my controller

```
$this->selectedUsers = UserTipepermintaanRelationship::where('permintaan_tipe_id', $id)->pluck('user_id', 'user_id');
```

the object above will give output:

```
1 => 1
2 => 2
25 => 25
```

and here in my html:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id[]', $users, isset($tipePermintaan) ? $selectedUsers : null, ['class' => 'form-control select-user', 'multiple']) !!}
```

i want to set my select2 multiple value with `selectedUsers`.

but i can't set the value on my select2 multiple. where do i do wrong?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4.* or the Laravel Collective?

Comment: can you provide full code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your code like:

```
{!! Form::select('user_id[]', $users, (isset($tipePermintaan) ? $selectedUsers : null), ['class' => 'form-control select-user', 'multiple']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->selectedUsers` is collection but for `Form::select` third parameter must be array with keys. So you need:

```
$this->selectedUsers = UserTipepermintaanRelationship::where('permintaan_tipe_id', $id)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```